# What should our tags be for the ending (song) of an episode and the ending (finale) of an anime be?

Tags: discussion, tags

Since just "ending" can have both meanings, we should differentiate questions about the actual anime ending (maybe tag with [plot](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plot)?) and the ending song / theme / ED ([ending-song](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ending-song)?).

What should the tags be?

Comment: The motivation comes from [this question](http://anime.stackexchange.com/q/175/20), which I wanted to tag with [tag:ending], until I realized the ambiguity (which also got me in the titel).

Answer (score 3):

"ending-song" implies that the tag is about the *song*, but there is also video there, so that doesn't make absolute sense, thus I wouldn't vote for renaming it like that. Also I'd say that the most used meaning of "ending" would be the episode's ending (song, that is) rather than the anime's plot ending.

So, I'd suggest leaving the "opening" and "ending" tags for the episode's opening and ending (i.e. songs), and making either "plot-ending" or "story-ending" for the story (IMO "story-ending" sounds a bit better).

I think two synonyms should be created as well: "OP" for "opening" and "ED" for "ending".

Note that it may be also useful to have tags for the music only, maybe "soundtrack" or "original-soundtrack" ( with a synonim "OST" ) tag for the soundtrack-related questions. Or maybe it should be names as simple as "music".

Answer (score 3):

For music related to an anime, wouldn't it be easier just to bundle then into one all-encompassing [music](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/music)?

Although most questions will probably concern OPs and EDs, sometimes there may be questions concerning insert songs, like "Alchemy" in *Angel Beats* or "God Knows" in *Haruhi*.

We can then add [opening-theme](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/opening-theme), [ending-theme](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ending-theme), [insert-song](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/insert-song), and/or [character-theme](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/character-theme) tag synonyms.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be better to use a tag that represents both the intro and outro songs, maybe something along the lines of "theme song", then the OP can describe which one or both they are referring to.

Comment: Ah, I just couldn't remember "intro" and "outro", that may do it.

Comment: I still stand by the theme song tag or maybe even music tag, having opening and music tags just looks messy, i.e http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/175/is-there-an-explanation-to-the-one-piece-anime-not-having-an-ending

Answer (score 0):

You could use episode-opening and episode-ending to clear any ambiguity, though I see OP and ED used more often.