# How should we deal with meta and dependent tags?

Tags: discussion, support, tags

*This is tangentially related are [there](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169/what-should-be-the-policy-regarding-character-specific-tags) [particular](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161/should-we-use-author-and-animation-studio-tags) [questions](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85/what-should-our-tags-be-for-the-ending-song-of-an-episode-and-the-ending-fina).*

This [Cooking.SE meta post](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/434/please-zap-the-meta-tags-and-dependent-tags) puts what I'm trying to say into context. This is the [official policy](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) on meta tags.

Are some of these <strike>non-series,</strike> tags appropriately used? <strike>technology</strike>,
[plot-explanation](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plot-explanation), [mistranslation](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mistranslation),[crossover](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crossover), [analysis](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/analysis), [sound-effects](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sound-effects), [meme](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meme), [zanpakuto](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zanpakuto), [quote](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quote), [boxing](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/boxing), [business](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/business).

Most of questions might only need the series tag. E.g., if you already have a tag for [akira](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/akira) adding [plot-explanation](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plot-explanation) seems redundant, because chances are you are asking about something plot-related (e.g. In the manga, why were Tetsuo and Kaneda fighting during the Y incident?). However, there might be some requires that require more context. E.g., if you want to know something specific about the author of Akira, tagging [akira](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/akira) and [manga-ka](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/manga-ka) might make more sense.

If you are asking about what certain "sound effects" mean, it might be more appropriate for JLU. But if you are asking about a specific interjection a particular series's character, like Kinomoto Sakura's "hoe" exclamation. It can easily just fall under the [card-captor-sakura](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/card-captor-sakura) series tag with maybe a [character](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/character).

Tags like [production](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/production) and [culture](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/culture) might be useful when asking general questions about anime/manga production (How did Type-Moon go about making Tsukihime?) and otaku subculture (Why are French maids the most popular type of maids in anime and manga?).

I'm unsure about tags like [tropes](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tropes) and [translation](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/translation) as a some question may be off-topic (In Japanese, why does X mean Y) or not constructive (what are a list of tropes found in Q series?).

How do we make sure the tags are properly utilized?

Should we make [guidelines](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61307/on-guidelines-to-tagging-and-avoiding-unnecessary-tags) for tagging non-series meta tags that don't correspond with any specific content, so we can avoid unnecessary/excess tags?

Answer (score 2):

Tags on other sites do not strictly conform to the "series" equivalents.

While Stack Overflow does have [php](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/php), [c++](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) and [python](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python), it also has [git](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/git), [forms](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/forms) and [display](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/display). Each of this do not strictly relate to any specific programming language (or in our case, series), but they do provide helpful information about the question.

After all, that's what tags are for, if we wanted series only tags, we would have to call them "categories", don't you think?

I don't consider [technology](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technology) a meta tag for instance. A meta tag is a tag which describes the *question*, and not the *content* of the question. An example for a meta tag is [spoilers](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spoilers), which doesn't give me any indication on what the content of the question is, but only tells me it has spoilers (which make it a bad tag).

I would agree though, [plot-explanation](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plot-explanation) seems redundant, as by default, that's what I as a read/answerer assumes the question is about. It is also on the border of meta-tag.

Comment: I'm not sure about if [tag:plot-explanation] is redundant. Among the front page questions, quite a large number are asking about things that are not plot-related (like http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/734/). There is a definite difference between that question and, say, http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/26. On the other hand, the tag has definitely not been applied consistently (http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/537 never should have gotten that tag). IMO we should try to find a more self-explanatory name for the tag first, and if that fails we can kill it.