# What tags are OK besides "series-name"?

Tags: discussion, tags

It seems like a lot of tags that are anything other than "series-name" become the subject of debate in meta. So, what other tags are actually OK? You don't really need to list every other tag that is OK. It would probably be more helpful to describe what makes some of these other tags acceptable.

I raise this question because it seems a little odd that so many questions only have one tag (their series name).

To quote [Madara Uchiha](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/301/how-should-we-deal-with-meta-and-dependent-tags/305#305) (the user, not the character):

> If we wanted series only tags, we would have to call them "categories", don't you think?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a general rule of thumb, ask yourself "Could there be an expert on this subject?"

There **can** be an expert on the following subjects (for example, not limited to):

- Naruto ([series-name-here](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/series-name-here))
- [anime-production](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anime-production) or [manga-production]
- [anime-history](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anime-history)

There probably **cannot** be an expert on the following:

- [characters](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/characters) and [character-abilities](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/character-abilities)
- [variations](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/variations)
- [opening-songs](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/opening-songs)

These tags are under discussion right now, we aren't sure about whether to keep them or not.

Comment: I'd put [tag:plot-explanation] in the second category as well.

Answer (score 5):

There are very few tags that make sense beyond the tag for a series name.

The only ones that generally make sense are for covering non-specific-anime topics, such as  [production](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/production), [anime-history](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anime-history), or [voice-actors](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/voice-actors).

There are a few other tags like [japanese-language](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/japanese-language), or [3d-animation](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/3d-animation)/[visual-effects](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visual-effects) or [doujinshi](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/doujinshi)/[fan-works](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fan-works) that could be added onto a series-name. The criteria for these is that someone who is not at all interested in a series might still follow these tags and be helpful for any random questioner. (respectively, a language student, an animator, and someone active in the doujin scene)